# What is the scope of a type alias?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.6

What is the scope of a typescript type alias?
I have this alias and I think that I might want to declare it globally somehow:

```
type ResouceResult<T> = T & {
    $promise: ng.IPromise<T>,
    $resolved: boolean
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 3.9 of Typescript 1.5 language specification: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf

> 3.9 Type Aliases
>
> A type alias declaration introduces a type alias in the containing module

so module

Answer (score 2):

> declare it globally

If your file is a global, the type alias is global. If its a module, the type alias is a module.

More on this: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/project/modules

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**:
The scope of a type alias follows **basically the same rules as variables**.

On how to **declare a type globally**:
See ["Global .d.ts"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html) and ["Create a global variable in TypeScript"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906359/create-a-global-variable-in-typescript).

### Long answer:

A lexical scope is the same for both, variables and types, as described in
["1.10 Namespaces"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.8.10/doc/spec.md#110-namespaces):

> ...each lexical scope contains a variable declaration space and type declaration space (see [section 2.3](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.8.10/doc/spec.md#23-declarations) for more details).

Scopes are defined in section ["2.4 Scopes"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.8.10/doc/spec.md#24-scopes) (but there are no surprises). In particular:

> The scope of a name depends on the context in which the name is declared ... :
>
> - The scope of a name declared in the global namespace is the entire program text.
> - The scope of a name declared in a module is the source file of that module.
> - ...
> - The scope of a local let, const, class, interface, type alias, or enum declaration declared immediately within the body of a function-like declaration is the body of that function-like declaration.
> - The scope of a local let, const, class, interface, type alias, or enum declaration declared immediately within a statement block is the body of that statement block
>   -- (See also: [5.1 Blocks](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.8.10/doc/spec.md#51-blocks))

A type alias is considered a "name" here (just like variables), which can also be implied from this sentence:

> When an identifier is resolved as a TypeName (section 3.8.2), only names in scope with a type meaning are considered and other names are ignored.

... where a type alias has a "type meaning" (of course):

> [2.3 Declarations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v1.8.10/doc/spec.md#23-declarations)
> Declarations introduce the following meanings for the name they declare:
>
> - ...
> - An interface, type alias, or type parameter declaration introduces a type meaning.