# Create a global variable in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In JavaScript I can just do this:

```
 something = 'testing';
```

And then in another file:

```
 if (something === 'testing')
```

and it will have `something` be defined (as long as they were called in the correct order).

I can't seem to figure out how to do that in TypeScript.

This is what I have tried.

In a .d.ts file:

```
interface Window { something: string; }
```

Then in my main.ts file:

```
 window.something = 'testing';
```

then in another file:

```
 if (window.something  === 'testing')
```

**And this works.  But I want to be able to lose the `window.` part of it and just have my `something` be global. Is there a way to do that in TypeScript?**

(In case someone is interested, I am really trying to setup my logging for my application.  I want to be able to call `log.Debug` from any file without having to import and create objects.)

Comment: Alternatively: Don't create globals. Importing is _really easy_ with vscode. Just type the thing you want to use, hit tab to auto-import, and continue on.

Comment: @DevinRhode Ideally that's the way to go. But sometimes you need to use a JavaScript library that declares global variables and want to use a typed version of it in your project.

Comment: It's true, actually I had a use for globals recently, and created a new approach, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76844373/565877

Comment: Typescript global declarations are more subtle than you might think. For a better understanding, I recommend these answers, one from here, one from a different question: [Create a global variable in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56984941/61624) [Using globalThis in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68452689/61624)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so this is probably even uglier that what you did, but anyway...

<sup>but I do the same so...</sup>

What you can do to do it in pure TypeScript, is to use the `eval` function like so :

```
declare var something: string;
eval("something = 'testing';")
```

And later you'll be able to do

```
if (something === 'testing')
```

This is nothing more than a hack to force executing the instruction without TypeScript refusing to compile, and we `declare var` for TypeScript to compile the rest of the code.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I have eval('myglobalvar = {};');. It results in: Uncaught ReferenceError: myglobalvar is not defined at eval (eval at <anonymous>..... ). Funnily though if I run it from the console then it works.

Comment: @RyanHow what browser do you use ? I tried it on mine and I can't reproduce your error

Comment: @DragonRock I tried Chrome and FF. So I'm really not sure what was going on. Anyway ended up doing declare var myglobalvar; (<any>window).myglobalvar= {}; Then I can reference it without window afterwards.

Comment: This really should be done with a `.d.ts` definition file instead.

Comment: This works for me: `export declare const SERVER = "10.1.1.26";`

Comment: Using `eval` is highly discouraged that's why I suggest using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/56984504/5506278

Comment: Using `eval` is dirty, consider using `Object.assign(globalThis, {something: 'something'})` instead

Answer (score 149):

[globalThis](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4/#type-checking-for-globalthis) is the future.

First, TypeScript files have two kinds of `scopes`

### global scope

**If your file hasn't any `import` or `export` line**, this file would be executed in **global scope** that all declaration in it are visible outside this file.

So we would create global variables like this:

```js
// xx.d.ts
declare var age: number

// or 
// xx.ts
// with or without declare keyword
var age: number

// other.ts
globalThis.age = 18 // no error
```

> All magic come from `var`. Replace `var` with `let` or `const` won't work.

### module scope

**If your file has any `import` or `export` line**, this file would be executed within its own scope that we need to extend global by [declaration-merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

```js
// xx[.d].ts
declare global {
  var age: number;
}

// other.ts
globalThis.age = 18 // no error
```

> You can see more about module in [official docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#introduction)

Comment: But how would you do this without the 'var' hack?  I guess that means, how would I do type augmentation on globalThis?

Comment: @Tom `var` is necessary. But you can just declare variable without initialization

Comment: Worked for me (at least for now) thanks so much, I wish this answer would move up. FYI: In my case I needed to add `// @ts-ignore` above the `globalThis` line for the linter.

Comment: How would you call the age variable in to any typescript file?

Comment: Even when this solution may work, the compiler is still complaining: 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.', and I don't think adding `// @ts-ignore` commend is a good practice

Comment: hi @AnthonyLuzquiños, I cannot reproduce the "complain" with TypeScript 4.4

Comment: Hi @edvardchen, I have created a [project](https://github.com/AnthonyLzq/test-global) in case you want to give it a try.

Comment: @edvardchen, I could finally solve the issue, it was related to ts-node, this is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610583/ts-node-ignores-d-ts-files-while-tsc-successfully-compiles-the-project) to that, I have also wrote a Medium article about it, [here](https://medium.com/@anthonylzq/how-to-create-global-variables-in-typescript-with-node-js-9ca24f648991) is it.

Comment: Is this only a declaration or also defining the variable? Can you initialize it in the global .ts file ?

Comment: @gwhiz only a declaration. You should always use globalThis to do the actual assignment. `var age = 123` won't work.

Comment: It's 2023 and this still works.

Comment: Doesn't TS just compile lets and consts down to a var anyway?  I don't understand why this works.

Comment: @JoeJohnston I think that depends on your tsconfig `target`. Most modern targets use let and const.

Comment: @edvardchen Any idea why `var` does the magic here? Is there any documentation for it? I can't find any

Comment: @Aelita That's how `var` works in the old days, unlike now when CommonJS and ESM are everywhere. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var).

"In a script, a variable declared using var is added as a non-configurable property of the global object."

Comment: @edvardchen Yeah that totally makes sense to me, but wondering if there's anywhere that in the TypeScript docs says `var` works the same way in the type system...

Answer (score 84):

Inside a `.d.ts` definition file

```
type MyGlobalFunctionType = (name: string) => void
```

If you work in the browser, 
you add members to the browser's window context:

```
interface Window {
  myGlobalFunction: MyGlobalFunctionType
}
```

Same idea for NodeJS:

```
declare module NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    myGlobalFunction: MyGlobalFunctionType
  }
}
```

Now you declare the root variable (that will actually live on window or global)

```
declare const myGlobalFunction: MyGlobalFunctionType;
```

Then in a regular `.ts` file, but imported as side-effect, you actually implement it:

```
global/* or window */.myGlobalFunction = function (name: string) {
  console.log("Hey !", name);
};
```

And finally use it elsewhere in the codebase, with either:

```
global/* or window */.myGlobalFunction("Kevin");

myGlobalFunction("Kevin");
```

Comment: ( Just making a passing comment ) Talk about a lot of work to create a simple global variable! lol

Comment: @Benoit I don't get the part that says "but imported as side-effect". What do you mean by that?. I tried doing this, but it's not working for me, could you share a source code example?

Comment: This works fine for `.ts` files but when I use `window.myGlobalFunction` in my `.tsx` files, it doesn't. What else do I need to change?!

Comment: Where do you put the d.ts file, and how do you configure TypeScript to load it?

Comment: This is ridiculously complicated.

Comment: Be aware that you have to name `*.d.ts` files without extra dots, i.e. `some.global.d.ts` file could not be recognized properly, but `some-global.d.ts` could (with a dash instead of the first dot).

Comment: typescript global object key's have any type...anyone knows why?

Comment: Note: the Node code is outdated now (since Node 16 apparently).
Instead just `declare global { var whatever }`

Answer (score 36):

This is how I have fixed it:

**Steps:**

1. Declared a global namespace, for e.g. custom.d.ts as below :

```js
declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface Global {
            Config: {}
        }
    }
}
export default global;
```

2. Map the above created a file into "tsconfig.json" as below:

```
"typeRoots": ["src/types/custom.d.ts" ]
```

3. Get the above created global variable in any of the files as below:

```js
console.log(global.config)
```

**Note:**

1. typescript version: "3.0.1".
2. In my case, the requirement was to set the global variable before boots up the application and the variable should access throughout the dependent objects so that we can get the required config properties.

Hope this helps!

Thank you

Comment: Since Node 16 use
`declare global { var whatever: type }`

Answer (score 21):

The text posted here is a short version of the article [TypeScript and Global Variables in Node.js](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/typescript-and-global-variables-in-node-js-59c4bf40cb31)

Since the release of TypeScript 3.4 there's a documented way to do it.

Create a file in the root of the project named `global.d.ts` with the following content. Please note:

- The use of var , it’s required for this to work (see [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#type-checking-for-globalthis) for information about this).
- Without the `export {}`, all variables will become `any`

```
declare global {
    var Config: {
        Foo: string;
    };
    var Foo: string;
}
export { };
```

Make sure the tsconfig.json has proper sections for `include` and `exclude`. Example follows:

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "<node_internals>/**",
    "bin/**"
  ]
```

To use the variables, just do something like:

```
import * as Logger from './logger';

// Initialize early
global.log = Logger;

// Use it
log.Info("Booting system...");
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Finally.. `export { };` was the key. In `.ts` you can use `global.log` or `globalThis.log` interchangeably.

Answer (score 19):

I found a way that works if I use JavaScript combined with TypeScript.

logging.d.ts:

```
declare var log: log4javascript.Logger;
```

log-declaration.**js**:

```
log = null;
```

initalize-app.ts

```
import './log-declaration.js';

// Call stuff to actually setup log.  
// Similar to this:
log = functionToSetupLog();
```

This puts it in the global scope and TypeScript knows about it.  So I can use it in all my files.

NOTE: I think this only works because I have the `allowJs` TypeScript option set to true.

If someone posts an pure TypeScript solution, I will accept that.

Comment: In your initalize-app.ts file you can use: `declare var log: any;`

Then you don't need to have the d.ts file or the js file. You could replace any with an actual type or an interface definition as well.

Answer (score 7):

I spent couple hours to figure out proper way to do it. In my case I'm trying to define global "log" variable so the steps were:

1) configure your `tsconfig.json` to include your defined types (`src/types` folder, node_modules - is up to you):

```
...other stuff...
"paths": {
  "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"]
}
```

2) create file `src/types/global.d.ts` with following content (**no imports!** - this is important), feel free to change `any` to match your needs + use `window` interface instead of `NodeJS` if you are working with browser:

```
/**
 * IMPORTANT - do not use imports in this file!
 * It will break global definition.
 */
declare namespace NodeJS {
    export interface Global {
        log: any;
    }
}

declare var log: any;
```

3) now you can finally use/implement `log` where its needed:

```
// in one file
global.log = someCoolLogger();
// in another file
log.info('hello world');
// or if its a variable
global.log = 'INFO'
```

Comment: What's the `paths` in `tsconfig.json`? The docs don't have any mention of it.

Comment: And why is `Global` capitalized in the definitions, but not in actual usage?

Comment: @tambre not sure why TS docs don't have it documented, you can find some details regarding this config here: http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig  and here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/project/tsconfig.html
Regarding `Global` with capital - this is how "global" interface declaration named in nodejs namespace.

Answer (score 6):

im using only this

```
import {globalVar} from "./globals";
declare let window:any;
window.globalVar = globalVar;
```

Comment: This throws away all type information. May as well use Javascript.

Comment: This solution makes sense when you are making frontend completely outside from backend (for different purposes), like different teams or due to security reasons. And then backend inject something inside window. I honestly prefer specify EACH variable inside components in this case. So I believer this solution might have a life :) Do not think this is wide case, but I faced with it one day....

Answer (score 5):

Extend the other answer about `globalThis` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) and [TypeScript 3.4 note](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#type-checking-for-globalthis)) with more specific examples (TypeScript only without mixing with JavaScript), as the behavior was fairly confusing. All examples are run under Nodejs `v12.14.1` and TypeScript `Version 4.2.3`.

### Simplest case with global scope

```
declare var ENVIRONMENT: string;
globalThis.ENVIRONMENT = 'PROD';
console.log(ENVIRONMENT);
console.log(globalThis.ENVIRONMENT);
// output
// PROD
// PROD
```

This file doesn't `import` or `export` so it's a global scope file. You can compile the above TypeScript code without any error. Note that you **have to** use `var`. Using `let` will throw `error TS2339: Property 'ENVIRONMENT' does not exist on type 'typeof globalThis'.`

You might notice that we `declare`d the variable as opposed to the following which also works.

```
var ENVIRONMENT: string;
ENVIRONMENT = 'DEV';
globalThis.ENVIRONMENT = 'PROD';
console.log(ENVIRONMENT);
console.log(globalThis.ENVIRONMENT);
// output
// DEV
// PROD
```

The output is from Nodejs `v12.14.1`. I also tested it in Chrome (after compiling to JS) and both output `PROD`. So I'd suggest using `globalThis` all the time.

### Simple case with module scope

```
declare var ENVIRONMENT: string;
globalThis.ENVIRONMENT = 'PROD';
export {};
```

Once we add `export` statement, it becomes a module scope file, which throws `error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.` The solution is to [augment global scope](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation).

```
declare global {
  var ENVIRONMENT: string;
}
globalThis.ENVIRONMENT = 'PROD';
console.log(globalThis.ENVIRONMENT);
export {};
```

You still **have to** use `var`, otherwise you will get `error TS2339: Property 'ENVIRONMENT' does not exist on type 'typeof globalThis'.`.

### Import for side effect

```
// ./main.ts
import './environment_prod';

console.log(ENVIRONMENT);
console.log(globalThis.ENVIRONMENT);
```

```
// ./environment_prod.ts
declare var ENVIRONMENT: string;
globalThis.ENVIRONMENT = 'PROD';
```

Or

```
// ./environment_prod.ts
declare global {
  var ENVIRONMENT: string;
}
globalThis.ENVIRONMENT = 'PROD';
export {}; // Makes the current file a module.
```

### Browserify two files

Suppose both `main.ts` and `environment_prod.ts` are entry files. [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) will wrap them (after compiled to JS) into local scoped functions which necessitates the use of `globalThis`.

```
// ./main.ts
declare var ENVIRONMENT: string;
console.log(ENVIRONMENT);
console.log(globalThis.ENVIRONMENT);

// ./environment_prod.ts
declare var ENVIRONMENT: string;
globalThis.ENVIRONMENT = 'PROD';
```

But it's more type-safe to share a declaration file which can then be imported by both entry files, to avoid typos of variable names or type names.

```
// ./main.ts
import './environment';

console.log(ENVIRONMENT);
console.log(globalThis.ENVIRONMENT);

// ./environment_prod.ts
import './environment';

globalThis.ENVIRONMENT = 'PROD';

// ./environment.ts
type Environment = 'PROD' | 'DEV' | 'LOCAL';

declare var ENVIRONMENT: Environment;
```

Note that the order matters: `browserify environment_prod.js main.js > bin.js`

Answer (score 4):

It is work on browser
I found this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12709880/15859431

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        myGlobalFunction: myGlobalFunction
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed to make lodash global to use an existing .js file that I could not change, only require.

I found that this worked:

```
import * as lodash from 'lodash';

(global as any)._ = lodash;
```

Answer (score 3):

Also check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64197006/11209037)

```
// global.d.ts
export const thisIsAModule = true; // <-- definitely in a module

declare global {
    var foo: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me, as described in [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18237):

```
declare let something: string;
something = 'foo';
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone uses Deno:

```
// global.ts
interface Global {
    some_number: number;
}

export const global = {
    some_number: 1,
} as Global;
```

Then every script that imports `global` can modify its values (but not `global` itself!) like this:

```
// test.ts
import { global } from "./global.ts";
export function test() {
    global.someNumber++;
}
```

You can prove that it works by running the function from another file:

```
// main.ts
import { global } from "./global.ts";
import { test } from "./test.ts";

console.log(global);
test();
console.log(global);
```

… will print:

```
{ someNumber: 1 }
{ someNumber: 2 }
```

Comment: This is better than most answers. You avoided creating `.d.ts`, and avoided touching `tsconfig.json`! But there's a funny thing in the code here: If we are already importing ane exporting, we can drop `interface Global { ... }` and `} as Global;` - just have a shared mutable `global` `Object` that you import/export and mutate as needed. If people can do this, given their constraints, it's definitely better than other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Read through all the existing answers, and I think I owe some credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67040805/565877 (@Yuxuan Xie). Not sure where this idea originated from, myself or someone else.

Anyway, this is my current strategy:

## Preconditions:

Let's evaluate the best strategy for you.

1. If you can have a shared mutable "global" object that you control, and simply import/export where you need it, that's better than mucking around with `globalThis` or `declare global` etc.
2. If you can "wrap" some other value with typescript, that's also great.

- `export const Object_keys_typed = Object.keys as SOME_TYPE`

## Lastly

If there's just some global being created outside of your typescript code, proceed.

## Define the globals

1. Create this file:
2. `define-globals-for-some-specific-thing.ts`
   Add add your code like this:

```
// Importing constants is fine:
// import type { FOO } from './constants';

// Import this in order to access these globals.
declare global {

  // Because this is a `const/let`, typescript will complain if you access it via `globalThis.WAS_LOADED_VIA_INDEX_HTML`,
  // You instead need to remove the `globalThis.` prefix
  /** determine if this was loaded via index.html, or some other npm/script tag function */
  const WAS_LOADED_VIA_INDEX_HTML: boolean | undefined;

  // This can be accessed via `window/globalThis.CanBeReadOffWindow`
  var CanBeReadOffWindow: 'asdf' | undefined;
}

// Makes the current file a module, with a clear importable name
export const defineGlobals = undefined;
```

## Use the globals:

Inside `myFile.ts`:

```
import './define-globals-for-specific-task.ts';

export const wasLoadedViaIndexHtml = () => {
  return WAS_LOADED_VIA_INDEX_HTML;
};
```

## Why this is good

1. We avoid touching `tsconfig.json`.
2. We avoid creating `.d.ts` files.
3. We're forced to use imports/exports where we want to access the globals.

- This means if you scan import statements to get the "gist" of a file, you can see it will interact with some globals defined in `define-globals-for-specific-task`.
- We can search for these import statements, and find everywhere we use a global

<sub>There's probably a better name template than `define-globals-for-specific-task` - perhaps `define-SPECIFIC_TASK-global-types`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As an addon to Dima V's answer this is what I did to make this work for me.

`// First declare the window global outside the class`

`declare let window: any;`

`// Inside the required class method`

`let globVarName = window.globVarName;`

Comment: Can the person who down-voted this explain the reason?

Comment: Well, this is a solution like putting a piece of black tape over your "check engine" light on your dashboard. It fixes the problem but not in the right way. It obliterates types. It's not an optimal solution; it's a workaround that also works around the main purpose of typescript: to have types.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create global variables for node app and typescript

File name is called `typings/index.ts`

```
declare global {
  var countSkipped: number;
  var countProcessed: number;
  var countLibUsedByFile: Record<string, number>;
}

export {};
```

If you happen to overrides a few prototypes, here's how you can add the typescript definition for the string prototype

```
declare global {
  interface String {
    blue(): string;
    yellow(): string;
    green(): string;
    red(): string;
  }
}

export {};
```

This is the sample prototype for the above string

```
String.prototype.blue = function () {
  return `\x1b[36m${this}\x1b[0m`;
};

String.prototype.yellow = function () {
  return `\x1b[33m${this}\x1b[0m`;
};

String.prototype.green = function () {
  return `\x1b[32m${this}\x1b[0m`;
};

String.prototype.red = function () {
  return `\x1b[31m${this}\x1b[0m`;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using this:

```
interface Window {
    globalthing: any;
}

declare var globalthing: any;
```

Answer (score -1):

**Firs declare your Global variable Like this**

```
declare global {
  var options: {
    billingAddress: {
      country: string;
      state: string;
      city: string;
      postcode: string;
      street1: string;
      street2: string;
    };
    mandatoryBillingFields: {
      country: boolean;
      state: boolean;
      city: boolean;
      postcode: boolean;
      street1: boolean;
      street2: boolean;
    };
  };
}
```

**In functions you can use Like this**

```
const updateGlobalVariable = () => {
      window.options = {
        billingAddress: {
          country: 'US',
          state: 'NY',
          city: 'New York',
          postcode: '12345',
          street1: 'Suite 1234',
          street2: 'Some Road',
        },
        mandatoryBillingFields: {
          country: true,
          state: true,
          city: true,
          postcode: true,
          street1: true,
          street2: false,
        },
      };
    };
```

Comment: I was specifically asking for a way to remove the `window.` part of the referencing of the variable.  (To reference it directly).  This still uses `window.` to get at the variable.  `window` is global here, not `options`.