# how can I declare a global variable in typescript

Tags: typescript

I declare a global variable in typescript something like:
        global.test = "something"
I try to do that I get the error property ‘test’ does not exist on type ‘Global’.

Comment: I've seen people do it a few different ways. You can setup global variables inside of a .ts file that just exports each variable. Or you can put them in a file that looks like the environment variables file and import that. You'll still have to import the globals file whenever you want to use the variables inside of it, though.

Comment: If it is a browser based typescript you can try window.test="something"

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906359/create-a-global-variable-in-typescript) SO question.

Comment: Why does this question (a duplicate of a much better SO entry) show up more and instead of the better one? The only reason I found the original is because @JeroenHeier made that comment.  Just the way web search works I guess. :|

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I try to do that I get the error property ‘test’ does not exist on type ‘Global’.

Create a file `globals.d.ts` with

```
interface Global {
 test: string;
}
```

## More

Declaration files : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html

Comment: export interface? needs export keyword?

Comment: This should be at the root of your source folder, also I needed to restart my VSCode for it to work...

Comment: That link leads to 'page not found'. This seems to be the new one: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/intro/d.ts

Answer (score 8):

in global.ts

```
export namespace Global {
    export var test: string = 'Hello World!';
}
```

in your.ts

```
import { Global } from "./global";
console.log(Global.test)
```

Comment: This is not actually global, since the import is still necessary, the answer from @basarat is actually global.

Answer (score 2):

Inside a global.d.ts definition file

```
type MyProfileGlobal = (name: string,age:number) => void
```

Config.tsx file

In React:

```
interface Window {
  myProfileFun: MyProfileGlobal
}
```

In NodeJS:

```
declare module NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    myProfileFun: MyProfileGlobal
  }
}
```

Now you declare the root variable (that will actually live on window or global)

```
declare const myProfileFun: MyProfileGlobal;
```

Use it elsewhere in code, with either[Add data]:

```
global/* or window */.myProfileFun("Sagar",28);

myProfileFun("Sagar",28);
```

Use it elsewhere in code, with either[Get data]:

```
global/* or window */.myProfileFun= function (name: string,age:number) {
      console.log("Name: ", name);console.log("Age: ", name);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to declare a global variable in typescript:

```
// foo.ts
interface IData {
    test: string;
}
declare global {
    var someVar: IData;
}
```

Now, in any other file in the project:

```
// bar.ts
import 'foo'
somVar.test = 'Yes !!!!'
```