# ts-node ignores d.ts files while tsc successfully compiles the project

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, ts-node

Having compiled my TypeScript project successfully, I intended to run it in VS Code's debug mode using `ts-node`. Problem is, `ts-node` can't find `d.ts` files I created (while `tsc` has no problem with it).

Project structure is:

```
/
    conf/
    dist/
    src/
        types/
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

`tsconfig.json` relevant entries are:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "commonjs",
        // "lib": [],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "node_modules/*",
                "src/types/*"
            ]
        },
        // "rootDirs": [],
        // "typeRoots": [],
        // "types": [],
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

The definition file `ts-node` can't find is `src/types/global.d.ts`:

```typescript
import { App } from '../App';

declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface Global {
            app: App;
        }
    }
}
```

So, trying to run it with `ts-node` I see:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/boot.ts(15,59): error TS2339: Property 'app' does not exist on type 'Global'.
```

How to resolve it globally? I've found that `/// <reference path="./types/global.d.ts" />` does the trick but I'd have to repeat it in every file using `global.app`.

My TypeScript version is 3.0.1

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Starting with ts-node in 7.0.0, does not Load files from `tsconfig.json` on startup. Instead, you should specificy `--files` like this

```sh
ts-node --files src/boot.ts
```

Comment: Yes, `--files` does the trick. I don't know however why `typeRoots` doesn't. It is the way to go according to https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#help-my-types-are-missing but I tried it and it didn't help. Anyway, `--files` worked but I had to find a way to wire it into VS Code's `launch.json`. Finally, I made a `ts-node.js` file in the project root that contained only: `require('ts-node').register({ files: true })` and referenced it in `launch.json`: `"runtimeArgs": [ "-r", "./ts-node.js" ]`. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You are my hero!

Comment: This just saved be from hours of messing around with type declaration files, ambient variables etc. Thanks a lot @Forseti!

Comment: Everytime I come across this issue, I always find this comment again and it solves the issue right away. I'm glad this comment will always be here for me.

Comment: Here's an explanation of the `--files` option, although I still don't get why it works: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1132#issuecomment-714582153

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will still forever question why TS-Node doesn't automatically do this, it just makes life harder. In fact there should be an option to disable it and make it enabled by default, not the other way round.

Comment: In VSCode, add `"env": { "TS_NODE_FILES": "true" }` in `launch.json` to ensure `ts-node` correctly loads all types during debugging.

Answer (score 289):

I was having a similar problem, but I could not add `--files`, because I run `ts-node` by registering the module through `mocha` (i.e. `mocha -r ts-node/register ...`).

I could solve it by adding a `files` and a `ts-node` section to `tsconfig.json` like this:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  },
  "files": [
    "src/index.ts",
    "src/global.d.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions":{
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked for me only using the `"ts-node"` section.  Thanks.

Comment: A great workaround for `ts-node` build but it completely throws off the `tsc` build.

Comment: Can confirm that only adding the `ts-node` section makes mocha compile again without breaking `tsc`, thanks @Sharpiro!

Comment: `files` is a Boolean flag, so this solution is just as as good as setting `"files": true` which apparently slows down the process.
I prefer to use `<reference path="./global.d.ts" />` where I use these

Comment: this reply needs more credit

Comment: You don't even imagine the time i spent looking for this

Answer (score 30):

**TLDR**

Add `"ts-node": {  "files": true },` in `tsconfig.json` for `ts-node-dev` to work as expected

**explanation:**

I was using `ts-node-dev` in `package.json` like:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    ...
    "dev": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts"
  },
```

`npm run build` was working fine but `npm run dev` was failing, My type definition files are in `src/types/*`.

It started working fine after I added the following in my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "ts-node": {  "files": true }, // add this
  "compilerOptions": {
     ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I spent way to much time on this issue tried almost everything like adding to typeRoots my typings folder, creating typing folder with structure typings/module/index.d.ts but nothing worked out so now I've figured it out now what the above answer meant

With a new version of ts-node I've changed for my project's scripts:

```
ts-node@6: ts-node src/index.ts
ts-node@7: ts-node --files src/index
```

So your script will be changed to something like below

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node --files src/index",
  }
```

With the above in action your compile time increase a lot but I couldn't spend more time on this so I'm sticking to the above.

You also might like to visit https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#missing-types.

Comment: That link you posted is the real solution (doesn't slow down compile time): use the `typeRoots` compiler option.

Comment: @AndrewKoster What if I want to define one custom type globally (e.g. `type Id = string;`) without need to import it everywhere. It works fine with `tsc` if it's defined in any `*.d.ts` file included in compilation, but does not with `ts-node`. How to avoid `--files` option here?

Comment: @AndrejLeitner The example is in the link: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#help-my-types-are-missing
It's multiple lines of code, so I can't really post it in a comment.

Comment: Yep, I've seen it, but the only one that worked for me was to pull the type definition file with `/// <reference path="./types/global.d.ts" />`

Answer (score 13):

Here's How i fixed it.   Add "nodemon --exec ts-node --files src/app.ts" to your dev script.

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node --files src/app.ts",
    "build": "tsc -p",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

Comment: This worked best for me. I've also tried `ts-node-dev` but this kept ignoring the files defined in `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 5):

While all the other solutions are good. ts-node suggested methods (other than using --files which is last resort according to ts-node) can be found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#missing-types.

It recommends 3 different types based on your use case and preferences.

1. Using compilerOptions.typeRoots in tsconfig.json

> For global definitions, you can use the typeRoots compiler option. This requires that your type definitions be structured as type packages (not loose TypeScript definition files). More details on how this works can be found in the TypeScript Handbook

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots" : ["./node_modules/@types", "./typings"]
  }
}
```

2. Using paths in tsconfig.json

> For module definitions, you can use paths

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "custom-module-type": ["types/custom-module-type"]
    }
  }
}
```

3. Using triple slash directive

> Another option is triple-slash directives. This may be helpful if you prefer not to change your compilerOptions or structure your type definitions for typeRoots. Below is an example of a triple-slash directive as a relative path within your project:

```
/// <reference path="./types/lib_greeter" />
import {Greeter} from "lib_greeter"
const g = new Greeter();
g.sayHello();
```

Comment: #1 didn't work for me but #2 did ‍♂️ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Including this code into tsconfig is enough

```
{
"compilerOptions": {...},
"include": [...],
"ts-node": {
  "files": true
},
}
```