# How do I make Typescript pick up a declaration file?

Tags: typescript, ts-node

My file `src/auth/ManagementAPI.ts` uses Auth0. I need to use my own declaration file and have created `src/@types/auth0.d.ts`.

However, when I run `ts-node`, I'm getting this error:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
auth/ManagementAPI.ts(1,69): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'auth0'. '/Users/danrumney/WebstormProjects/ohana/node_modules/auth0/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/auth0` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'auth0';
```

I've updated my `tsconfig.json` file to include:

```
"typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types",
    "./src/@types"
]
```

My declaration file is like this:

```
declare module 'auth0' {
  /*...*/
}
```

Why is this declaration not being picked up?

I've created an example repository here: https://bitbucket.org/ohanapediatrics/so-demo/src/master/

Comment: Do you have an example repo or can you spin up an example on stackblitz?

Comment: Does your auth0 declaration file name is `auth0.d.ts` within your `./src/@types` directory ? And the good practice is to put your third-party libraries local declaration files within a `./types` directory. You don't even have to add it in the config, it's automatically parsed.

Comment: UPDATE: The error is when I use `ts-node`, not `tsc`

Comment: Added git repo: https://bitbucket.org/ohanapediatrics/so-demo/src/master/

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610583/ts-node-ignores-d-ts-files-while-tsc-successfully-compiles-the-project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the `typeRoots` mechanism to load your declaration file, it needs to be named `index.d.ts` and placed in a *subdirectory* of one of the directories listed in the `typeRoots` option; see the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types).  Based on the `typeRoots` setting in your repository, you could put the file at `src/types/auth0/index.d.ts`.

The above will work, but since your declaration file is declaring a module, it would be better practice to set up module resolution to find your declaration file instead of using `typeRoots`, which is mainly intended for global declarations.  To do that, either use [`baseUrl` and `paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) or create a `package.json` file for a local npm package named `@types/auth0` and register the package in your main `package.json` file using a relative path.

Comment: Thanks! From the docs: > A types package is a folder with a file called index.d.ts or a folder with a package.json that has a types field.