# How to send emails via "smtpjs" in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, smtp, smtpjs

I want to send a email via form whenever user clicks submit

and for that i use `smtpjs` package you can check the site in here https://smtpjs.com/

in pure js we must add this line of code in html head tag

```
<script src=
    "https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js">
  </script>
```

and then we can use `Email.send({})` to send the email

but for react

i tried to add the mentioned code(script tag) in head in `index.html`
and tried to use it as `Email.send({})` and `window.Email.send({})`
and it didn't recognize `Email`
so my question is how can use the library in react since i added it in index.html

### EDIT:

i got this error when sending email

```
  The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not 
  authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn 
  more at - Fix: Try a different SMTP server : 
  https://elasticemail.com/account#/create-account?r=20b444a2-b3af-4eb8-bae7- 
  911f6097521c
```

i enabled less secure app for google and also turned off 2-step verification but it doesn't help

Comment: When the script is loaded it creates a global object `Email`. You can access any global object in your React code like this `window.Email`. But if I were you I would try to find out if the lib follows any js module pattern that would enable you to import it like `import Email from 'smtpjs';` Does your project use `package.json` and the usual ecosystem of webpack, babel, etc.?

Comment: Yes it does, i just tried `window.Email` looks like lin is not downloaded correctly to create the global object because it shows me this error `Property 'Email' does not exist on type Window & typeof globalThis`. any advice about that?

Comment: Is this a runtime exception or just typescript doesn't know `window.Email`? You can declare it to exist on window.

Comment: I think type script doesn't recognize it because when i write `window` and the add a dot to it, it doesn't suggest Email word . How can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

Your `<script>` tag is adding a property `Email` to the global `window` object, but TypeScript doesn't know about this.  You need to tell TypeScript that this property exists and what type it is.

Since this package is really simple I went ahead and create a type declaration file.  I followed the guidelines and examples in the [TypeScript docs on Global Libraries](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html#global-library-template).

```
// Type definitions for SmtpJs
// Project: https://smtpjs.com/
// Definitions by: Linda Paiste https://github.com/lindapaiste

// SmtpJS exposes a variable `Email` on the global `window` object
declare namespace Email {
  type Attachment =
    | {
        name: string;
        path: string;
      }
    | {
        name: string;
        data: string; // base64 format
      };

  interface EmailData {
    SecureToken: string;
    To: string | string[];
    From: string;
    Subject: string;
    Body: string;
    Attachments?: Attachment[];
  }

  function send(email: EmailData): Promise<string>;
}
```

I will publish this to `@types/smtpjs.com`, but for now I included it in the `src` directory of the project.

Now we need to get TypeScript to read this file and include its types.  As explained in [this answer by Matt McCutchen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53326434/10431574), the file should be named `index.d.ts` and it should be in a directory which has the name of the package.  That directory should be inside a directory of package types.

I think that you can skip a few steps here if you are able to put your file at `./src/@types/smtpjs/index.d.ts`.  CodeSandbox does not allow for special characters in names, so I had to use the location `./src/types/smtpjs/index.d.ts` without the `@` and tell TypeScript about this types directory using the [`typeRoots` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) in `tsconfig.json`.

```
"compilerOptions": {
...
  "typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types/",
    "./src/types"
  ]
}
```

Once everything is set up, you get full TypeScript support when accessing `window.Email` or `window.Email.send()`.  If you want to access the specific types to use them for variables, you can use `Email.EmailData` and `Email.Attachement`.

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/including-typescript-types-for-script-tags-ibo6i?file=/src/types/smtpjs/index.d.ts)

Comment: It also doesn't recognize `Email` when i run commands `npm install` and then `npm build` for deployment

Comment: I have no idea about the authentication issue.