# mocha and ts-node cannot find local .d.ts file

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, ts-node

I have the following project structure

```
|_typetests
|          |_type.test.ts
|
|
myproj.d.ts
tsconfig.json
```

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "lib": [
          "es6"
      ],
      "target": "es6",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "types": [
          "node",
          "mocha"
      ],
      "noEmit": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "include": [
      "types/*.test.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

If I run `./node_modules/.bin/tsc -p . --traceResolution`

Then I can see:

> Module name 'myproj' was successfully resolved to '/Users/paulcowan/projects/myproj/myproj.d.ts'. ========

But when I run the following through mocha

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha -r ts-node/register types/*.test.ts
```

`Error: Cannot find module 'myproj'`

Answer (score 15):

Try use `--files` flag to solve your issue.

Or set `TS_NODE_FILES` environment variable to `true` and try again

`TS_NODE_FILES=true ./node_modules/.bin/mocha -r ts-node/register types/*.test.ts`

Comment: still no cigar, is there anything I can do debug this better, I don't think it is picking up the tsconfig.json

Comment: @dagda1 try add `typeRoots` option to you tsconfig file. `"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./myproj.d.ts"]` and try again with, without my option.

Comment: same deal, I don't think it is picking up the tsconfig.json

Comment: ts-node loads tsconfig.json automatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610583/ts-node-ignores-d-ts-files-while-tsc-successfully-compiles-the-project

Comment: aha, looks promising

Comment: `TS_NODE_FILES` worked for me; I put it right in a script command in `package.json`: `"scripts": { "test": "TS_NODE_FILES=true mocha -r ts-node/register tests/**/*-test.ts -r ts-node/register tests/*-test.ts"}`

Comment: This worked for me:
`./node_modules/.bin/mocha --require ts-node/register --require tsconfig-paths/register --preserve-symlinks --max-old-space-size=4000 wiski-libs/types/global.d.ts`

Comment: Note: instead of setting the environment variable in the "scripts" section of package.json, you might prefer to set `process.env.TS_NODE_FILES = true;` in your file .mocharc.js.