# Cannot run ts-node with .tsx files

Tags: typescript, docker, jsx, tsx, ts-node

I have created a React app with Typescript and JSX (creating .tsx files instead of .ts) which I am attempting to run in a docker container with hot reloads but with little success.

I've tried using nodemon in conjunction with ts-node but keep running into the error

> [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".tsx"

One suggestion was to remove "type": "module" from the package.json file but this leads to the error;

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I get caught in a loop in SO between [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096269/cant-run-my-node-js-typescript-project-typeerror-err-unknown-file-extension/62099904#62099904) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import/64655153#64655153)

Does anyone know how to solve either this specific issue of getting ts-node to work with tsx files or more generally how to enable hot reloading of typescript with JSX inside a docker container?

Comment: @CraZyDroiD as of the time of writing I have not and have since moved around the problem, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

- Try setting `compilerOptions.module` to `CommonJS` in your `tsconfig.json`
- Don't put `"type": "module"` in `package.json`

Proof of concept:
https://github.com/ferdinandant/stacko-unknown-ext-tsx

---

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "include": ["src", "types/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules/**"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610583/ts-node-ignores-d-ts-files-while-tsc-successfully-compiles-the-project
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "stacko-unknown-ext-tsx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.tsx",
  "author": "Ferdinand Antonius",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node src/index.tsx"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
}
```

`src/index.tsx`

```
import fs from "fs";

console.log("Hello!");
console.log(fs);
```

Run it as `yarn ts-node src/index.tsx`

Comment: for me it was the `"esModuleInterop": true,` that made it happen