# Type error with express middleware generator function

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have a function, that takes a middleware function, wraps it into a try catch block and then returns back a middleware function.

#### tryCatch.ts

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

export default function tryCatch(controller: (req: Request, res: Response, next?: NextFunction) => Promise<any>) {
  return async function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {
    try {
      await controller(req, res, next);
    } catch (error) {
      // do some logging first, then call next
      return next(error);
    }
  }
};
```

#### Route handler

```js
import express from 'express';
import tryCatch from './tryCatch';
import someAsyncHandler from './controller/someAsyncHandler';

const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
router.post('/foo', someAsyncHandler);
//                  ^ this works
router.post('/bar', tryCatch( someAsyncHandler ));
//                  ^ this doesn't work
```

It gives the following error:

> No overload matches this call.
> The last overload gave the following error.
>
> Argument of type '(req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to parameter of type '**Application<Record<string, any>>**'.
>
> Type '(req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction) => Promise<...>' is missing the following properties from type 'Application<Record<string, any>>': init, defaultConfiguration, engine, set, and 63 more. ts(2769)

Before switching to Typescript, this worked fine. What am I doing wrong or is it just Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out, what the issue was. As it often is, it was something completely different.

The actual issue was that I am using **ts-node** and it didn't recognize the declaration merging I did for the `Response` type. Funny enough, VS Code was able to recognize the correct types.

The solution was to add the `--files` flag to the command ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51666714/6608142)). For reference, here are my settings.

#### package.json

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon"
  }
}
```

#### nodemon.json

```json
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts,json,js",
  "ignore": ["src/**/*.spec.ts"],
  "exec": "ts-node --files src/app.ts"
}
```