ts-node ignore file global.d.ts or tsconfig.json?
I have a nodeJs project with typescript and then a tests for it;
i use mocha do this tests
.mocharc.json
{
  "extension": [
    "ts"
  ],
  "spec": "tests/*.spec.ts",
  "loader": "ts-node/esm", // use ts-node 
  "require": [
    "chai/register-expect.js"
  ],
  "recursive": true,
  "timeout": 20000
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node16/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["src", "global.d.ts"]
}

global.d.ts
declare global {
  const __TEST__: boolean;
}

export {};

and then the ide can correctly resolve the global  variable "_TEST__"

but when i run mocha, it failed :

i find this issure : https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/635
it refer ts-node just starts from the input file and discovers the rest of the project tree through imports and references
so how i can create a global variable with ts-node , such as __DEV__ , __TEST__  ....

i resolve it by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610583/ts-node-ignores-d-ts-files-while-tsc-successfully-compiles-the-project
