# How to prevent VS Code autocorrecting "debug" to "debugger" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, keyword

Basically, we are using a particular flavor of Javascript at work that has the word `debug` as a keyword. I am using VS Code for development, and it's driving me nuts that it always autocorrects `debug` to `debugger`. Is there any config file I can use to tell VS Code to stop having me press backspace 3 times or having my program crash if I don't notice? Pretty sure it's a recent thing too.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by _"autocorrects"_? I've never had VSCode change anything I've typed after I've typed it. Try not pressing Tab or Enter when the suggestions come up

Comment: If I type `debug(` the second I put the `(` there it autocorrects. It didn't use to, but it definitely does now... Our project was recently converted to Typescript, could that be the culprit? I disabled the error logs for that one...

Comment: What version (I'll check against mine)? So you type `d-e-b-u-g-(` and at that last keypress, it changes `debug` to `debugger` (I'm just trying to establish exact reproduction parameters)?

Comment: See the edited question / gif

Comment: I can reproduce this on mine (1.30.2) but only if I don't define the `debug` symbol. Eg, if I put `import { debug } from 'util'` or `function debug() { }` first, it doesn't auto-complete

Comment: But this is a special debug, not the `util` debug :(
The language we're using defines the symbols in XML... I can't edit code in that way...

Comment: It was just an example. Why isn't `debug` imported / required / etc into the current script?

Comment: It's background setup, language-specific symbols are defined in an XML. I can't edit the code to define the symbol..
So there is no configuration file where I can define keywords?

Comment: I'm still learning TypeScript but does this help ~ https://stackoverflow.com/a/43523944/283366. Basically, I would try and define the `debug` function / interface so VSCode picks it up