# Extending built-in types in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webdriver-io, typescript3.0, ts-node

I have the following structure:

```
project
 |- types
    |- global.d.ts
    |- string.d.ts
    |- wdio.d.ts
 |- src
    |- Models
    |- Resources
    |- Components
    |- Extensions
       |- string.ts
    |- ...
 |- tsconfig.json
 |- wdio.conf.js
```

I try to extend the string's prototype with a function. I tried so far a lot of way, I found on several sites. But either the `tsc` gives me error, or the PHPStorm shows error message.

```js
// types/string.d.ts
declare interface String {
    myCustomFn(text : string) : string;
}

// src/Extensions/string.ts
String.prototype.myCustomFn = function(text : string) : string {
    // ... Logic

    return 'myCustomFn';
};

// tsconfig.json
...
    "typeRoots": ["./types/"],

    "include": [
      "./src/**/*.ts",
      "./types"
    ]
...

// wdio.conf.js
...
before: function (capabilities, specs) {
    require('ts-node').register({ files: true });

    require('../extensions/String');
},
...
```

I added the augmentation for the `String` class to the d.ts file. Then I define the body of the function in a separate file. When I implement it in the `src/Extensions/string.ts` file, the `tsc` command gives no error message, BUT the PHPStorm shows the following error:

`TS2339: Property 'myCustomFn' does not exist on type 'String'.`

Moreover, anywhere in the code the auto-completition shows my method, and even the code can be executed, and uses the `myCustomFn` function.

**Questions:**

- Is this just an error of the IDE?
- Am I doing something wrong or should the way, how the String class is being extended be in different way?

Answer (score 7):

Full working example on [Github](https://github.com/a1300/Zoltan_Fekete_typescript_string_prototype)

Place your `String` interface extension in a random `.d.ts` file:

```js
interface String {
  myCustomFn(text : string) : string;
}
```

Add another file `extension.ts` where you add the `prototype`:

```js
String.prototype.myCustomFn = function(text : string) : string {
  return 'myCustomFn';
};
```

Then import the `extension.ts` file into your root `index.ts` file:

```js
import './extension';
```

Now you can add your `String().myCustomFn(text: string);` everywhere you want.

> P.S. it is important that you **include** the `.d.ts` file to your compilation files.
>   The `typeRoots` property is not necessary.

`tsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "types" // here is the .d.ts file
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's the thing. I doing exactly the same thing. 

There is a `.d.ts` file - in which I extend the prototype with a function.
In another file I write the implementation of that function.

On the initialisation of the code I require the file. 

I provided more info about my files. Btw: this is a webdriver-io project. In the `before` callback I require the file. And the code runs. What I don't understand why does the IDE marks it as an error.

Comment: If your .d.ts file imports anything, TypeScript won't consider the module to be "in the global scope" anymore, as it's now a "module". To fix this, you'll need to put your interface inside of `declare global { ... }`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56984941 for more context.

Comment: What if the type you extend has a generic? And what if you want to use the "base" object in the function?