# How can I add expect() to the global namespace with Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am able to make the linter recognize `global.expect` as a variable with the following

```js
// types.d.ts
namespace NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    expect: any
  }
}
```

However, it won't autocomplete any of `expect()` methods. I figure it's cause it's `any`.

I'm trying to type it to the expect imported type but it's not working, Here's what I've tried.

```js
import expectExport from 'expect';

namespace NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    expect: expectExport
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where *is* expect coming from? Have you installed the types for that package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a global variable in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906359/create-a-global-variable-in-typescript)

Comment: @Shlang I tried that, but it's particularly the expect library that I don't understand how the types are exported

Comment: I missed the point you want to use it as `global.expect` not just `expect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Do the following in `global-expect.ts`:

```js
import expectExports from "expect";

declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface Global {
            expect: typeof expectExports;
        }
    }
}

global.expect = expectExports;
```

Make sure you import/execute the file somewhere at your application's entry point, e.g. `index.ts`:

```js
import "./global-expect";
```

Then you can use this anywhere:

```js
global.expect(...); // (property) NodeJS.Global.expect: <...>(actual: ...) => Matchers<...>
```

### Explanation

1. the `NodeJS` namespace is in the `global` scope so it must be declared that way inside of a module:

   ```js
   declare global {
     namespace NodeJS {
       ...
     }
   }
   ```
2. the ***type*** `expect` property in the `Global` interface must be a ***type*** of the `"expect"` exports - not the instance of it. So it must be declared like this:

   ```js
   expect: typeof expectExports;
   ```
3. then you actually have to set the property:

   ```js
   import expectExports from "expect";

   ...

   global.expect = expectExports;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A bit simpler way to accomplish it is to augment NodeJS namespace in some `d.ts` file

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
        expect: typeof import("expect")
    }
}
```

It also may be handy to use expect as a global variable, so you can make a `global.d.ts` file near to `tsconfig.json` and put declaration there

```
// global.d.ts
declare const expect: typeof import("expect");
```