# typescript error accessing globalThis property

Tags: javascript, typescript

i am trying to access the `globalThis` property, but get the error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature`.
```

```
// both getting...
if (!globalThis.foo) {}

// and setting...
globalThis.foo = 'bar
```

the only thing i can find online about this, refers to using `window`, and provides declarations to support it, but not for globalThis. anyone know how to support this?

Comment: You should provide code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Wyck i added some example code, but i get the error literally doing anything with globalThis

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [the `globalThis` documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#type-checking-for-globalthis), it looks like the "right" way to do this is to declare a global `var` named `foo`.  That will add to `globalThis`.

If your code is in global scope, then this will work:

```
var foo: string;
```

If your code is in a module, you need to wrap that in a `global` declaration:

```
export const thisIsAModule = true; // <-- definitely in a module

declare global {
    var foo: string;
}
```

After that, you should be able to access `globalThis.foo` as desired:

```
globalThis.foo = "bar"; // no error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7xgCwJaoJKoCCAshACYCuANsHALxwxQXADcAsAFBnAJUCGUWgHMqEAEb8qcAN5c4CuADdBcAGYQIALjjoo2ZMI6cAvly6iJUgCo5UAOg0R6cAESSor1nAD0PuMjOwFBQ0OacQA)

Comment: so simple... ty!