# Property 'users' does not exist on type 'Global & typeof globalThis' although modifying global with global.d.ts

Tags: typescript, global-variables

I am trying to develop a project in the one I need to include global variables that could be accessed from anywhere. Normally, with javascript I would be able to write something like this: `global.users = {}` but this is not that easy in typescript, therefore, I need to modify the interface of the `global` variable. After some research I tried including in `global.d.ts` the following code:

```
// global.d.ts

declare module NodeJS  {
    interface Global {
        users: {[key: string]: import("./src/server/classes/User").User}
    }
}
```

Which actually made the VS Code Intellisense errors dissappear, but when I run `ts-node` the errors appear again:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/server/index.ts:22:8 - error TS2339: Property 'users' does not exist on type 'Global & typeof globalThis'.

global.users = {};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56984504/2983489

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it still does not work. I tried to recreate your example, but the same error appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to follow https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-declare-global-variable in order to do it.
Using the module format (`declare global { var users: ... }`) didn't work for me, but the non-module `global.d.ts` did:

```
declare var users: ...
```

Make sure you don't have any `import` or `export` statement in your `global.d.ts`. However, `import()` type expression like the one you used is OK.