# Typescript is throwing a type error when using global.mongoose

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I'm trying to implement chaching to my database connection file, for my next.js app so I won't have to go through the connection process all over again when I interact with the database.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const uri: string = process.env.MONGO_URI!
```

But after adding the following line of code, when I hover on mongooseI keep getting the **"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.ts(7017)"** error and I couldn't figure out why.

```
let cached = global.mongoose
```

Just a note, before adding the line above there was no error in the file

```
const opts: object = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    bufferCommands: false,

}
const connecter = () => {
    console.log(typeof globalThis.mongoose)
    mongoose.connect(uri, opts).then(mongoose => {
        return console.log('Database connection established')
    })
}
export default connecter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add this declaration before that line of code

```
declare global {
  var mongoose: any; // This must be a `var` and not a `let / const`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to link: [Create a global variable in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906359/create-a-global-variable-in-typescript).

define mongoose connection instance in the globalObject explicity.

```js
import { Connection } from "mongoose";

declare module NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    mongoose: Connection
  }
}
```