# how to set global variable in React Native in typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I want to set a global variable in react native. It is neccessary and seems like only option in my particular usecase. I'm using typescript with my project. The problem is typescript complains when I set something like `global.foo = bar;` with the error **"Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'typeof globalThis'."** I have tried to create a declaration file like this -

```
declare module NodeJS {
    export interface Global {
        foo: any;
    }
}
```

and also with some other methods that I found online for react native or NodeJS. None seem to be working. Do anyone have any idea why this is not working. I have declared other modules in the same fashion and they all are working except the global one. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You can cheat and do this:

```
(global as any).foo = bar;
```

And when you need to access it, also use `(global as any).foo`

Obviously it's a bad practice both from the type safety point of view, and polluting the global namespace, but you've said it was the only way for you case...

Comment: I'm using **// @ts-ignore** and **// eslint-no-undef** with `(foo as typeof foo)` as of now. With this I'm getting typescript intellisense as well on the `foo` object. But I wanted to have a solution of this. Seems like I'm not finding any.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56984941/3568340).

In short, things seems to have changed from [TypeScript 3.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-4/#type-checking-for-globalthis), globalThis is now used and with it NodeJS's global variable.

The answer for me was quite simple, in a *.d.ts file:

```
declare var foo: any
```

Which actually seems sensible; you're declaring a global type the same way you would if it was a global variable.