# how can i use native fetch with node in typescript (node v17.6)

Tags: node.js, fetch-api

In the console, when running `node --experimental-fetch` the `fetch` command is now natively enabled (node version >=17.6). see below

[image: native fetch with node]

However, when I add a typescript layer, I always get `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'fetch'`.

how can I solve this?

background idea: use fetch natively and get rid of `node-fetch` and `@types/node-fetch` dependencies

`tsconfig.json` and general setup: https://github.com/nexys-system/server-boilerplate/blob/master/tsconfig.json

see also:

- [Fetch API has landed into Node.js](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=30161626)
- [fetch() In Node.js Core: Why You Should Care](https://fusebit.io/blog/node-fetch)

Comment: Given that it's experimental it's presumably not yet in `@types/node`.

Comment: can I create a PR in `@types/node`? Any other way I can hack my way around it? i.e. define `fetch` globally or so?

Comment: 1. Yes, you can create a PR on the DefinitelyTyped repo where those types are defined. 2. Yes you can also declare additional global types, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43523944/3001761.

Comment: I made it work, here's a sample repo: https://github.com/nexys-system/node-koa-fetch: PRs and suggestions welcome

Comment: As a hacky workaround, you can extend your `lib` section in `tsconfig.json` with `"dom"`. This includes the types for `fetch` but also a lot of other built-ins that are available only in browser, so be careful.

Comment: Hey, I'm still having trouble with this. I'm on node 18.9.0 with the latest `@types/node` (18.7.18) and it's still giving me the "Cannot find name 'fetch'" error. I'm targeting es2022 in my tsconfig file and including node types. Interestingly, a quick search through the @types/node package shows there is no fetch defined.... Am I missing something?

Comment: @kael actually it worked for me because Dom was enabled. Without it i think it still fails :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are only 2 easy/lazy solutions at the moment (check [Ruben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75676044/599991) for a proper one):

1. You can set `"lib": ["dom"]` in your `tsconfig.json`
2. You can add `/// <reference lib="dom" />` at the top of the files in which you use `fetch`

I personally prefer #2 as I can more easily keep track of where I am using this hack.

Beware that "*this tells TypeScript that you intend to run this code in a browser environment, allowing you to use DOM-specific globals. This makes type checking more lax and can lead to unexpected runtime errors*".

Comment: This is a wrong answer! As others pointed out, this tells TypeScript that you intend to run this code in a browser environment, allowing you to use DOM-specific globals. This makes type checking more lax and can lead to unexpected runtime errors.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 19):

Please don't import the whole lib dom from the typescript package or add the node-fetch package for types as some people do. Cause ...

1. Importing lib dom adds a lot of things to your globals that aren't available in node environments.
2. Adding the node-fetch to your project only for types, adds only the required types, but sadly they aren't complaint to the W3C fetch() specs. See: https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/main/docs/v3-LIMITS.md

What is somehow correct indeed, is to import the package "undici". As this package is the base for node's fetch() implementation, it provides the correct types.
Source: https://nodejs.org/de/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/#fetch-experimental

I recommend adding a .d.ts file to your project, with the following content:

```
import * as undici_types from 'undici';

declare global {
  export const {
    fetch,
    FormData,
    Headers,
    Request,
    Response,
  }: typeof import('undici');

  type FormData = undici_types.FormData;
  type Headers = undici_types.Headers;
  type HeadersInit = undici_types.HeadersInit;
  type BodyInit = undici_types.BodyInit;
  type Request = undici_types.Request;
  type RequestInit = undici_types.RequestInit;
  type RequestInfo = undici_types.RequestInfo;
  type RequestMode = undici_types.RequestMode;
  type RequestRedirect = undici_types.RequestRedirect;
  type RequestCredentials = undici_types.RequestCredentials;
  type RequestDestination = undici_types.RequestDestination;
  type ReferrerPolicy = undici_types.ReferrerPolicy;
  type Response = undici_types.Response;
  type ResponseInit = undici_types.ResponseInit;
  type ResponseType = undici_types.ResponseType;
}
```

**This obviously requires you to install the package 'undici' as well via your package manager of choice!**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/undici

For the ones super interested in this, there is a discussion ongoing in the DefinitelyTyped repository on github about it:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/60924

Comment: thanks! do you know when we can expect this to be part of typescript OOTB?

Comment: You're welcome. Sadly not. People expecting it to be added, as soon as node does not consider this feature experimental anymore.

Comment: This helped greatly, I was originally going down the path of including the `"@types/node-fetch": "^2.6.2",`, everything coded out right, however when I went to run the code I was hit with missing module for `node-fetch`.  Dropping the `@types/node-fetch` and removing the imports from my .ts files along with this above solution got me back on track, thanks.  

I'm currently running with 
node: v18.15.0
package.json: "@types/node": "^18.15.3"
tsconfig.json lib: ["ES2020"]

Once the @types/node package contains the types for fetch I can then remove this temporary .d.ts file.

Comment: Another note, I did not have to install the undici package, as node has it included already in my current version v18.15.0

Answer (score 4):

This GitHub issue "[node@18.x.x version not fetch global api ?](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/60924)" for `"@types/node"` is still open, to quote the latest comment from one of maintainers,

> The short version is that no one has implemented the types for fetch
> in this package yet. There are some ideas about how best to handle it
> but I don't know if there is actually a consensus among maintainers of
> this package. If you'd like to help with that, DT has good guidelines
> for getting started as a contributor, and I'm sure several people on
> this thread would be eager to review a MR.

There are proposed workarounds but I think maybe the easiest way is just to use `// @ts-ignore` above the `fetch` clause as we know for sure it is correct so we don't need ts check here.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to what @zVictor said, but I recommend to wrap the hack in it's own file.

Create a file "fetch.ts" in your project, with this content:

```js
/// <reference lib="dom" />

type _Response = Response;
const _fetch = fetch;

export type { _Response as Response };
export { _fetch as fetch };
```

Then you can import `fetch` from the rest of your project and you don't need to clutter your codebase with `/// <reference lib="dom" />` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, post-2023, Node.js v18+, the least-hassle answer is to just install and import `undici`, all types are in place there now:

```bash
npm install --save undici
```

```js
import { fetch } from "undici";
```

([source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/60924#issuecomment-1748235824))