# How can I use TypeScript for JavaScript loaded via script tag?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js

I'm currently bringing TypeScript into an existing Vue2/Nuxt(v2.15) project, and have ran into an issue. On one page, I bring [mapbox-gl](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/guides/install/#quickstart) in via CDN. As it's below the fold, I lazy load this in via a `script` tag that is created once the document has finished loading. I use this approach for other 3rd party code elsewhere.

```
// helpers.ts

export const onLoad = (callback: Function, delay = 1) => {
  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    setTimeout(() => callback(), delay);
  } else {
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      setTimeout(() => callback(), delay);
    })
  }
}
```

```
import {onLoad} from "./helpers";

export default ({ $config }) => {
  if ($config.environment === 'production') {
    onLoad(() => {
      const script = document.createElement('script')
      script.src = "https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.7.0/mapbox-gl.js"
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)
    })
  }
}
```

This works well, however I'm now looking to bring TypeScript into the mix. The issue is, TypeScript doesn't recognise `mapboxgl`.

References to `mapboxgl` properties (eg. `mapboxgl.accessToken`) are flagged as an issue in my IDE. When I hover over to see the details of the issue, I get:

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'mapboxgl'.
```

I've tried installing [@types/mapbox-gl](https://www.typescriptlang.org/dt/search?search=mapboxgl) via. `npm i @types/mapbox-gl --save-dev`, but this hasn't resolved the issue. I think this approach only works if I install `mapbox-gl` as a dependency in the project, which I'm keen to avoid- I'd rather lazy load 3rd party code in via scripts.

So the question is, how can I use TypeScript for javascript loaded via script tag?

EDIT:

I think the suggested question/answer is helpful, but doesn't completely answer the specific question I'm asking. Declaring `mapboxgl` as a global variable would suppress the IDE error, but how do I then map that declaration to the types provided by `@types/mapbox-gl`? Also, the suggested question/answer has the title "Create a global variable in TypeScript"- not something that's likely to come up when people are searching for a solution for "How can I use TypeScript for JavaScript loaded via script tag?". I think a more focused answer could benefit others.

Comment: Please don't attach images of code or — in this case — errors. See e.g. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: You have to declare your type on global window object than it will be available globally in your scripts:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a global variable in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906359/create-a-global-variable-in-typescript)

Comment: I've updated my question @CodeSpirit

Answer (score 0):

You would create a .d.ts file add it to your tsconfig.json types/typeRoots.
Then you import the type of global mapboxgl object and declare it on window.

```js
// I dont know excact type name of mapboxgl so this is an example
import {mapboxgl} from "mapboxgl";

interface Window {
  mapboxgl: mapboxgl;

  anotherCustomProperty: number;
}
```

Then you should be able to use `window.mapboxgl` in your script and it references the correct type.