# Typescript - Triggering all class decorators in source/Requiring runtime to declare all classes

Tags: typescript, decorator

I have a class decorator called "EntityType" which allows me to define a string lookup key to a class which maps to its constructor.

MyClass.ts:

```
@EntityType("MyClass")
export class MyClass {}
```

EntityType.ts

```
export function EntityType(key: string) {
    return (constructor: Function) => {
        
        if(!key){
            key = constructor.name;
        }

        let impl = new (constructor as any)();
        ENTITY_TYPE_MAP[key] = impl;
    }
}
```

main.ts

```
let myClassInstance = getEntity("MyClass");
```

However when I run my Typescript project "getEntity("MyClass");" will fail unless the class declaration for MyClass is included in the import chain for main.ts. Assumedly what is happening is that MyClass.ts is never executing so the decorator logic does not trigger.

How do I require all classes in the project to be declared at runtime so that all @EntityType decorators are executed? I know that a bundler can be used to just dump everything into one .js and run it but I am trying to avoid it as I am trying to have a simplified build process.

I'm running on the latest version of npm.

Comment: You might be looking for globalThis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906359/create-a-global-variable-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

I think, for doing this you need meta programming. In Zig you has comptime, in nim, rust, c you has macros - but not in javascript (`bun` has macros, but it's not ideal solution - switching runtime).

If you want have executed decorators before program starts and you don't want to bundle all code in one file - you need write script that will runs over each file and collect needed data in some json for example. Then you import and using collected data instead of runtime data.

---

Or, you just need to move your decorator logic to separate file and import it instead:

```
export const ENTITY_TYPE_MAP = {
  MyClass: new MyClass // or `new (await import('MyClass'))`
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I require all classes in the project to be declared at runtime so that all @EntityType decorators are executed?

This is usually done in an `index` file where you import or export all your classes. Here you would also have imported/exported your `MyClass`, so whenever someone imports `index.js/ts` your decorator gets instantiated.

While `export` is the best way to ensure `MyClass` is being instantiated, `import` has a twist! If you don't end up using the `import`, TypeScript will remove it post compilation.

From [TypeScript Docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-imports-being-elided-in-my-emit)

> TypeScript assumes that module imports do not have side effects, so it removes module imports that aren't used in any expression.

So you have to use import "mod" syntax to force the module to be loaded.

```
import "./myMod"; // For side effects
```