# Make a function in a Typescript bundle created with webpack, globally accessible in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm developing a plugin for a tool. The plugin is just a zip file, and the tool only looks for and loads `main.html` file. Thefore, any JS must be **inlined** in the HTML file.

I'm trying to develop with separate **Typescript** files and then have `webpack` bundle all the `.ts` files into a `bundle.js` and inline it in the HTML.

I managed to this but there's one problem. How to call the logic in the bundle from the HTML?

Webpack creates `__webpack_modules__` IIFE variables for the code in the bundle.

```
<head>
<script>bundled JS</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<script>
// How to call here an init() function in the bundle?
</script>
```

I tried to setup `iife: false` with no luck:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to explicitly export to the global object by assigning to `window`.

```html
<script>
  (() => {
    function myFn() { console.log('myFn ran') }
    window.myFn = myFn // assign to global object here.
  })()
</script>

<script>
  myFn()
</script>
```

Then if you want typescript type available for that, see: [Create a global variable in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906359/create-a-global-variable-in-typescript)

Comment: Thanks but the `window.myFn = myFn` is not run. That's the issue. I think webpack creates and wraps my TS code in a module.

Comment: Do you have a very simple repo with an example which shows how to bundle two TS files and expose a global variable or function?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to export your bundle as a library that we can use in a different script. If so, the option [output#library](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary) comes to help so the only thing you need to do is to export it as library with `umd` format which works great for both node and browser envs.

```js
{
   output: {
    // ...
    library: {
      name: 'yourLib', // you then can access it via window: `window.youLib`
      type: 'umd',
      umdNamedDefine: true,
    },
}
```