# Call function imported from <Script> in NextJS

Tags: typescript, next.js

In vanilla JS I am able to do

```
<head>
  <script src="https://api.site.com/js/v1/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

and then

```
const fn = ScriptJS();
```

and then use it:

```
const someOutput = fn.execute({input})
```

However in NextJS (with TypeScript) I am not sure how I achieve this without getting a reference error or dynamic import error.

Maybe I need to declare a type?

Loading via  tag in the thepage.tsx gives `ReferenceError: Script is not defined`

Loading via  tag in _app.tsx gives `ReferenceError: Script is not defined`

Loading via require() or import() gives `The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a global variable in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906359/create-a-global-variable-in-typescript)

Comment: "The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax" you can also set your tsconfig output to something other than "ancient": https://caniuse.com/es6-module-dynamic-import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider declaring the type in `.d.ts` file like this

```
declare global {
  let ScriptJS: () => void;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work to put it in .d.ts because of some global module issue- but adding that directly to my file worked. Thanks and learned something new about TypeScript :)