# How to declare a global variable in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, global-variables, typescript-typings

A site that I'm testing using Playwright has a certain non-standard object (say, `MY_OBJECT`) available on the `window`.
I'm calling this object using `page.evaluate`, like so:

```
page.evaluate(
  () => MY_OBJECT.someMethod()
)
```

Of course, my Playwright project doesn't know anything about `MY_OBJECT`, so I'm getting an error.

How do I correctly declare MY_OBJECT, so that it is available in the global scope without additional imports, etc.?

I tried creating `index.d.ts` and adding the following:

```
declare global {
  var MY_OBJECT: {
    someMethod: () => void;
  };
}
```

or

```
declare var MY_OBJECT: {
  someMethod: () => void;
};
```

but neither does work. I'm still getting
`TS2304: Cannot find name 'MY_OBJECT'.`

Comment: i remind you to this helpufl answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906359/create-a-global-variable-in-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an `export` statement to your `index.d.ts` file.

```
export {};

declare global {
  var MY_OBJECT: {
    someMethod: () => void;
  };
}
```

And make sure the `"include"` property in your `tsconfig.json` contains a glob pattern that matches `index.d.ts`

```json
{
"include": ["**/*.ts", ...]
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding that pattern in ```include``` solved the problem. I thought if my IDE recognized the type, TS could do as well...