# How can I share the value of variable into all classes / files in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, static, global-variables

apologies if I asked a simple question since I am a beginner in typescript.

I need to share my variables cross over the application in src/test etc. directories... My variables are going to be declared into file1 and update their values from file2 and can be accessed all over the application from their get methods.

For example

**File1 (SysParam.ts)**

```
export class SysParam {
private static _domain: string;
private static _env: string;

    public static get domain(): string {
        return SysParam ._domain;
    }
    
    public static set domain(value: string) {
        SysParam ._domain = value;
    }
    
    public static get env(): string {
        return SysParam ._env;
    }
    
    public static set env(value: string) {
        SysParam ._env = value;
    }

}
```

**File2 (setup.ts)**

```
async function startUp() {
//some database calls.
SysParam.domain=result.recordset[0].domain;
SysParam.env=result.recordset[0].env;

console.log("this is my domain from setupfile: " +SysParam.domain)
}
```

**File3 (example.ts)**
`console.log("this is my domain from examplefile: " +SysParam.domain)`

I also make sure setup run first / initial of program so everytime variable values should be presented, and in the results of file2 i do get console log but in file3 i got undefined.

`this is my domain from setupfile: xyz.com`

`this is my domain from examplefile:  undefined`

**NOTE**
I could not use .env here since my variables need to be updated time by time depending on needs. Also, I don't want to get a database call for the same record every time.

2nd I tried to use global.d.ts but not working either since it is only for declaring the variable not assigning their value and the same above-mentioned behavior has been observed.

The same thing I have already achieved in JAVA and it works fine and all my variables are holding their values until my program ends. But I am confused here in js/typescript.

Can someone please guide me with the complete implementation guide?

Comment: [Do not export a `class` with only `static` members when what you actually need is an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572). TypeScript is not Java, you don't have to put everything in a `class`.

Comment: How do you execute your program? How are the files included, where is the entrypoint? It looks like you should be using modules, where you import the file1 declarations into file2.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question you asked directly - almost any language supports global variables, [and TS is not different in that aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906359/create-a-global-variable-in-typescript) -

However - having global variables is [usually not the solution](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/global-variables) And you would probably like to simply export the class and import it everywhere you need it. classes are being passed by ref in TS so when updating the class it would "update" the ref as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how your program is organized, but you'd like to have SysParam.ts loaded first, then setup.ts, and finally example.ts.

Your `setup.ts` works as a kind of initializer, the message `this is my domain from examplefile:  undefined` from `example.ts` suggests the `startUp` function in `setup.ts` did not run. You'll want to export it in `setup.ts`, import it in `example.ts` and execute it.

```js
// setup.ts
import { SysParam } from './SysParam.ts'

// Function is defined, but not executed
export async function startUp() {
  //some database calls.
  SysParam.domain=result.recordset[0].domain;
  SysParam.env=result.recordset[0].env;
  console.log("this is my domain from setupfile: " +SysParam.domain)
}
```

And:

```js
// in example.ts
import { SysParam } from './SysParam.ts'
import { startUp } from './setup.ts'

(async () => {
  await startUp();
  console.log(`this is my domain from examplefile: ${SysParam.domain}`)
})()
```

Comment: In your solution, the startup function is not executing again? As I said above startup does execute first and console.log shows the domain variable value (as I mentioned above `this is my domain from setupfile: xyz.com`), and I don't want to execute a database call another time for the same record.

Comment: I believe your `setup.ts` is truncated: it does not export any function - and it does not execute `startUp`. If you were to load `setup.ts` in memory, `startUp` would not be executed. How did you get "this is my domain from setupfile: xyz.com" to print? I would guess that you called `startUp()` in `setup.ts`, or exported it and called it somewhere else. 

The snippet I wrote suggests to only run example.ts:
- SysParam.ts is read, it exports an empty SysParam object
- setup.ts is read, it exports (but does not execute) startUp.

Then startUp is called (once), and the statement is printed.