npx esbuild does not like export declare
In index.tsx we have:
import { permissions } from './permissions';

Where permissions is declared as:
export declare var permissions : {
/* contents omitted for brevity */
}

Typescript compiles the import line to:
import { permissions } from './permissions';

while permissions.ts compiles to:
export {};

thus causing the following build error from npx esbuild:
No matching export in "out2/permissions.js" for import "permissions"
    out2/index.js:2:9:
      2 â import { permissions } from './permissions';

If it would just close its eyes and believe, this code would function but rather it produces this meaningless error. It looks like the problem started with a recent update to npx; the code has been like this for months.
permissions is a page global; it always exists by the time index.tsx begins to load. permissions.tsx just declares the type for type checking.
How do I tell esbuild it's wrong, shut up?

Why are you using declare ?

@Evert: How else would you get tsc to recognize a global variable it doesn't already know about?

It looks like you are exporting/importing this value though, not creating a global.

@Evert: I am not creating a global; I'm declaring a pre-existing global.

So unless you are writing javascript with separate definition files, you don't need to do this. Just write export const permissions = {} and so on.

@Evert: export const permissions = {} will not work. It needs to pick up the global variable initialized in index.cshtml.

Got it, so there is a global defined externally. Looks like you might need the declare global syntax tehn. There's some information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906359/create-a-global-variable-in-typescript

@Evert: So the idea is to have one copy of the global variable declaration, not one copy per typescript file. Also, what's confusing to me is what I show here used to work.

Once that global declaration is done, you should no longer need to do it per typescript file. The empty export does actually kinda makes sense to me, because your permissions declaration file doesn't do anything by itself, it just declares a new type.

But yeah I would expect you to have to define permisssions.ts, once, which does one declare global, and you need to import it once somewhere in your app. After this, this global type should just be picked up without requiring explicit imports in other files.

@Evert: Well then; I'll find out at work tomorrow.

@Evert: Ok so that worked with export {} declare global {; write up answer. You earned it.
